# Проверьте, пожалуйста, согласование в предложении. Как бы вы переформулировали предложение для большей ясности?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Если мы следуем методу, в котором с помощью корректных логических рассуждений определяется истинная, с точки зрения трех типов анализа, суть доктрины Маркса, то в итоге обретем особую убежденность в верности его позиции.

Есть сомнение касательно "обретем". Не должно ли быть - "обретаем" из-за "следуем"?
Нет ли рассогласования из-за наличия вставки " с точки зрения трех типов анализа"? К такой вставке с позиции правильного согласования можно придраться?

Comment: Не совсем понятно: существуют некие три типа анализа для отличения истинной сути от неистинной?

Comment: Да, так и есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, в исходном варианте заметно несоответствие между "следуем" (в данный момент; возможно, и перестанем - лучше "будем следовать/придерживаться") и *будущим* "итогом". Достаточно изменить так:

> "Следуя методу... мы в итоге обретём..."

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. А нет также рассогласования из-за наличия вставки " с точки зрения трех типов анализа"? К такой вставке с позиции правильного согласования можно придраться?

Comment: Придраться можно в том смысле (и в том случае), что (если) перед этим предложением не были растолкованы или хотя бы названы упомянутые типы анализа.

Answer (score 1):

**А если покороче:**

Определяя истинную, с точки зрения трех типов анализа, суть доктрины Маркса с помощью корректных логических рассуждений, мы в итоге обретем особую убежденность в верности его позиции.

Comment: Можно было бы и так. Но в данном случае принципиально сохранить "следуем методу".